# Google Chart not displaying in browser / JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am attempting to graph a time series using Google Charts, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am attempting to display a line chart.

I have an html file that correctly is downloaded to the client browser but nothing is displayed.  That file is named gasdata.html

There is a call to a php file that outputs (via echo) some json file for the above-mentioned .html file to consume.

1. Is there a flaw in my json (it does validate correctly)?
2. Have I improperly implemented the Google Charts html in my html file?

There aren't many moving parts here, but I am at a loss.  Any help is much appreciated.

gasdata.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Outputted json:

```
{
  cols: [{label: 'Date', type: 'date'},
         {label: 'Production', type: 'number'}
  ],
  rows: [{c:[{v: new Date(2015, 3, 18)},
             {v: 76}
        ]},
         {c:[{v: new Date(2015, 3, 17)},
             {v: 75}
        ]},
         {c:[{v: new Date(2015, 3, 16)},
             {v: 74}
        ]},
         {c:[{v: new Date(2015, 3, 15)},
             {v: 73}
        ]},
         {c:[{v: new Date(2015, 3, 14)},
             {v: 72}
        ]}
    ]
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I should add that the json above is outputted by getData.php.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is broken. JSON is not allowed to have objects such as `Date`, and object keys must be wrapped in quotes (specified as strings).

See http://json.org/ to find out more about what's allowed in JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Evert.  I am wondering if the Google Charts implementation is more JSON-like as opposed to pure JSON.

This link seems to indicate quotes aren't always needed...

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

Comment: I mentioned above that the JSON validates, I should have been more specific.  I have tried this with the current JSON-like output above as well as truly-validated JSON with proper quote wrapping.

Thanks again.

Comment: @TravisMillburn their docs don't mention JSON, because it's not JSON, it's javascript!

Comment: So you can't use jQuery like this to load in your javascript, because jQuery will only accept valid JSON and should fail. JSON is a subset of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  Here is what I needed to get it to work.  As Evert noted above, the JSON was mal-formed.  There were also problems with my html.

Here is an example of good JSON:

```
{"cols": [{"label":"Date","type":"string"},
         {"label":"Production","type":"number"}],
  "rows": [{"c":[{"v":"3/5/2015"},{"v": 76}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"3/4/2015"},{"v": 75}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"3/3/2015"},{"v": 74}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"3/2/2015"},{"v": 73}]},
         {"c":[{"v":"3/1/2015"},{"v": 72}]}]}
```

Additionally, here is some good html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});



      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getLinesData.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;


        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```